# How to convert the Unicode of a number to the number itself in Java?

Tags: java, unicode

How to convert the Unicode of a number to the number itself in Java?

```
char c ='2';
int x =c;
// here x=unicode of 2, how can I put the 2 itself in x?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
int x = Character.getNumericValue(c);
```

or

```
int x = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(c));
```

Note that the second approach requires two conversions since Integer.valueOf can only handle other ints and Strings.

Comment: it works but can i change the unicode of a number to the number it self ?

Comment: Please state what you mean exactly with the "Unicode". Do you mean the `50` which `x` becomes when you do `int x = c` or do you mean a unicode string like `Ux0032`?

Comment: why this work ? and give  x=5
  char c='5';
  
  int x=c-'0';

Answer (score 2):

The most general solution is

```
int x = Character.digit(c, 10); // interpret c as a digit in base 10
```

The fastest solution, although it doesn't do anything to handle bad inputs, is

```
int x = c - '0'; // subtracts the Unicode representation of '0' from c
```

Comment: what is the logic behind the subtraction used in the second solution?

Comment: You're subtracting the ASCII value of `c` from the ASCII for `'0'`; that number is always the same as the digit value itself.

Comment: Ah, that was simple. So in the context of subtraction, char is auto-converted into its equivalent int.